# Lucene English tokenizer gives weird words

Tags: scala, parsing, lucene, nlp

I am using english tokenizer to parse out tokens and I am facing a weird situation where words like really/reply gets converted to realli, repli.

Below is the code snippet that I am using.

```
object Learning {

  def tokenize(content: String): Seq[String] = {
    val tReader = new StringReader(content)
    val analyzer = new EnglishAnalyzer()
    val tStream = analyzer.tokenStream("contents", tReader)
    val term = tStream.addAttribute(classOf[CharTermAttribute])
    tStream.reset()

    val result = mutable.ArrayBuffer.empty[String]
    while(tStream.incrementToken()) {
      result += term.toString
    }
    result
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(tokenize("This deal looks really interesting, I will look into it and reply"))
  }

}
```

This prints out as - ArrayBuffer(deal, look, realli, interest, i, look, repli). As far as I can see, there are no words such as realli,repli in the english language.

Can anybody point why this is giving output in such a way?

Comment: If you want the base forms (lemmas) of the words instead of artificial stems, look for a "lemmatizer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of a Lucene analyzer is to take character sequences from a source (provided by a parsing procedure) and produce a token stream according to the intended analysis. The EnglishAnalyzer performs stemming by default, yielding tokens that are not necessarily valid English words. In that case, a token "repli" may be the output for multiple English words holding the same semantics: "reply", "replied", "replying", "replies".

Therefore, a short answer would be "it doesn't matter, words were conveniently stemmed by the analyzer". If this is not the intended behaviour, you should be able to make a custom analyzer using a different stemmer (or removing it altogether). See the [documentation on analyzers](http://lucene.apache.org/core/6_2_1/analyzers-common/index.html) for additional information and a list of stemmers made available.